# MySQL sort by the number of LIKE match

Tags: sql, mysql

For the following query -

```
SELECT * FROM problem WHERE `type` LIKE '%river%' OR `description` LIKE '%accident%';
```

I want to have the results in the orders -

1. Where the records that have both conditions true are sorted first, then the ones that have the first condition true, and finally the ones that have the second condition true.
2. Where the records that have the first condition true are sorted first, then the ones that have the second condition true, and finally the records that have both conditions true.

Is it possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Order By with CASE

```
SELECT * FROM problem 
WHERE `type` LIKE '%river%' OR `description` LIKE '%accident%'
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN `type` LIKE '%river%' AND `description` LIKE '%accident%' THEN 1
    WHEN `type` LIKE '%river%' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
  END;
```